# Why are giving a union type to a variable and giving the same type to a parameter so different?

Tags: typescript, union

Using the `tsc --strict` command I get the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'T'.   Property
>   'foo' does not exist on type 'Bar'. 16   console.log(obj.foo)

What I don't understand is why I can assign the object literal to `obj` but get an error using the same property inside the function. Thanks!

```js
type Foo = {
  foo: string
  xyz: string
}

type Bar = {
  bar: string
  xyz: string
}

type T = Foo | Bar

let obj: T = { foo: "foo", xyz: "xyz" }

const sayHello = (obj: T) => {
  console.log(obj.foo)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign to a union you can assign either one of the constituent types from the union. This is why the assignment succeeds

When you try to access a parameter/variable of a union type, you don't actually *know* which of the union constituent types will actually be in it. It could be wither of them, so typescript considers as safe only access properties that are common to all members of the union. In your example accessing `xyz` is safe as it exists in both union constituents

You need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in order to get the compiler to narrow the type of the parameter to either one or the other constituent types:

```
const sayHello = (obj: T) => {
  console.log(obj.xyz) // ok common 
  if ('bar' in obj) {
    obj.bar // ok
  } else {
    obj.foo //ok
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClAZggLigGdgAnASwDsBzLHADxAC8jTLasBfLLUSKACEAhmWRp6UAEai25anWxQmrEvM6YemPuGgAVcfEQAfIaN6YANhGBQ4UgFZEDKVHkJQARPjieANMosRJ4qnlBaWADGcFSkJMIgABIQlpaIKAAU9k5QegCUyAB8EkrRsXDWAHRpNFmOlSoFAPRNdgDWUNEAtl0xUJIUuFAZAOQyZCNQ1HaOBRhKONmV41At7ZJcUCnE0PM4i-U+q01wbRvcQA)

Comment: Thx, this helped a lot. I actually tried another kind of type guard as well before I posted this question but it failed. I tried to use `if (typeof obj.foo==="string")`. Although your reply already helped a lot, do you maybe know some keywords which are useful to google or to search for in the official doc? Ty

Comment: @Take `typeof obj.foo==="string"` can't do the job unfortunately because t begin with `obj.foo` is not valid. Not really sure what other search term except union and type guard would be useful here. Maybe you will find this useful as well as to why even if `obj.foo` were valid it would still probably not narrow `obj`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you yet unfortunately (15 points needed).

Answer (score 0):

The type `Foo` is more specific than the type `Foo | Bar`. If you have a box which you can put `Foo | Bar`s, in, then you can put a `Foo` into that box, no problem. The variable `obj` and the parameter also named `obj` are the same in this regard; you can assign either a `Foo` or a `Bar` to the variable, and you can call the function with either a `Foo` or a `Bar` as the argument.

The difference is when you try to get `obj.foo` from `obj` which has type `Foo | Bar`. The `.foo` property is only defined on things of type `Foo`; but the parameter `obj` isn't necessarily a `Foo`, it could be a `Bar` instead, so it doesn't necessarily have a `.foo` property. That's why you get an error.

But you'll get the same error if you try to do `console.log(obj.foo);` with a variable of type `T` outside the function. It has nothing to do with being a parameter or not.

In your specific code, you don't see this error because even though you declared `obj` to have type `T`, Typescript knows that you've assigned a `Foo` to it, so because of control-flow type narrowing the variable is actually of type `Foo` after the assignment, and will remain as such until the variable is reassigned. If you change the declaration to avoid narrowing with an `as T` type assertion, then the error will appear as expected:

```js
let obj: T = { foo: "foo", xyz: "xyz" } as T
console.log(obj.foo); // type error
```

Comment: Thank you! This reply helped me, as well, although I am not so sure about your last sentence. If I understood it correctly, it might be wrong, because I can run `console.log(obj.foo)` without error outside the function. But maybe I understood it incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see the issue - even though you declared the variable as type `T`, Typescript has done control-flow narrowing so that `obj` has type `Foo` after the assignment. If you change the declaration to `let obj: T = { foo: "foo", xyz: "xyz" } as T` so it doesn't narrow, then `obj.foo` will be an error because `obj` will have genuinely have type `T`.